# How can I write the contents of array cells in the matlab to Excel using loops?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to write the content of a cell array (1x4) in a Excel sheet.

`cell({1,1})` contains a string (`'glcm11'`); `cell({1,2})` contains `'glcm12'`), `cell({1,3})` contain `'glcm13'`, and `cell({1,4})` contains `'glcm14'`.

I want to write the strings `'glcm11'`, `'glcm12'`, `'glcm13'`, and `'glcm14'` in the `a2:25` range, the strings `'glcm21'`, `'glcm22'`, `'glcm23'`, and `'glcm24'` in the `a6:a9` range, and the strings `'glcm31'`, `'glcm32'`, `'glcm33'`, and `'glcm34'` in the `a10:a13` range.

How I can write these cells in a Excel sheet using loops?

Answer (score 0):

To write the cell array with no loop 5 times:

```
filename = 'glcm.xlsx';

% Create a cell array in the form:
% {'glcm11'}    {'glcm12'}    {'glcm13'}    {'glcm14'}
% {'glcm21'}    {'glcm22'}    {'glcm23'}    {'glcm24'}
% ...
% {'glcm51'}    {'glcm52'}    {'glcm53'}    {'glcm54'} 
C = compose('glcm%d%d',(1:5)',1:4);

% Reshap the cell array to one column in the form:
% {'glcm11'}
% {'glcm12'}
% {'glcm13'}
% {'glcm14'}
% {'glcm21'}
% {'glcm22'}
% {'glcm23'}
% {'glcm24'}
% ...
% {'glcm54'}
C = reshape(C', [numel(C) 1]);


% Write cell array starting frim 'A2':

% For Matlab R2019a and newer:
writecell(C,filename,'Range','A2');

% For older versions of Matlab:
xlswrite(filename,C,1,'A2')
```